# How to display the username instead of login button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, local-storage

I have the following part in a header (in the index.html file):

```
<div class="rightsidetext">
    <div class="usernameDisplay" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="loginbutton" id="signOutButton" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
    <div class="loginbutton"><a href="signin.html">Sign in</a></div>
    <div class="loginbutton"><a href="Login.html">Log in</a></div>
</div>
```

When the site is loaded the first time, the login and signin buttons are displayed. After the user logs in, I want the two buttons to be replaced with the respective username and the log-out button.

In the js file linked to index.html (replaceWithUsername.js) I have:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const usernameDisplay = document.querySelector('.usernameDisplay');
    const signOutButton = document.getElementById('signOutButton');
    const signInButton = document.querySelector('.loginbutton a[href="signin.html"]');
    const loginButton = document.querySelector('.loginbutton a[href="Login.html"]');
  
    // Retrieve username from localStorage
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
  
    if (username) {
      // Show username and sign out button
      usernameDisplay.textContent = username;
      usernameDisplay.style.display = 'block';
      signOutButton.style.display = 'block';
  
      // Hide sign-in and log-in buttons
      signInButton.style.display = 'none';
      loginButton.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      console.log('No username found');
    }
});
```

At the end of signin.html I have:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          const inputField = document.getElementById('wantedSpace');
      
          // Listen for changes in the input field
          inputField.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
            const username = event.target.value; // Get the value entered by the user
      
            if (response.status == 200) {
              console.log('Username found:', username);
      
              // Set username in localStorage
              localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);
              localStorage.setItem('username', username);
      
              // Redirect to index.html
              window.location.href = '/allPages/index.html';
            } else {
              console.error('Login failed. Please try again.');
            }
          });
        });
</script>
```

The HTML where the user puts its username is:

```html
<input type="text" name="usernameOrEmail" placeholder="Username or Email" class="login_page_input" id="wantedSpace">
```

Also, I have the login route (in node.js, it is connected to a mongoDB batabase):

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { usernameOrEmail, password } = req.body;

  try {
      // Find user by username or email
      const user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ username: usernameOrEmail }, { email: usernameOrEmail }] });

      if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).redirect('/allPages/registration_feedback/sign_in_feedback/userNotFound.html');
      }

      // Compare entered password with hashed password
      const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

      if (!passwordMatch) {
          return res.status(401).redirect('/allPages/registration_feedback/sign_in_feedback/incorrectPassword.html');
      }

      console.log('Loged in user:', user);

      const token = generateToken(user);

      return res.status(200).redirect('/allPages/index.html');
  } catch (err) {
      console.error('Login error:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login failed. Please try again.' });
  }
});
```

After I log in a user, in the VSC terminal I do get the coodinates of that user, but in the browser the navbar remain the same (with the login and signin buttons, without the ussername) and in the console the following message appears:

`no username found  replaceWithUsername.js:24`

How do I make the username to appear on the page?

Comment: What is `response` in `if (response.status == 200)`? That looks like it comes from code that processes an AJAX response, but there's no AJAX in your code.

Comment: The response works, partially:
1. It does log the correct user, for example:
 Logged in user: {
   _id: new ObjectId('657dfcf51368621f677f2b21'),
   username: 'test30',
   email: 'test30@gmail.com',
   password: '$2b$10$v6iwWCNFgdFhEJ.39OycyuSSgd3t2Da5j6xqJ0v6NhyVHaoVyKEIS',
 __v: 0
 }
2. The site is redirected to index.html
3. in the localstorage, "isLoggedIn" is set to "true", but "username" appears to be empty.

Comment: How can the response work? There's no code that makes the request. Did you leave it out of the question?

Comment: Perhaps I didn’t phrase it correctly. The answer (what the function does, its result) is what I wrote above. As for what triggers it, I do set the status 200 for the response in the last line of the “try” statement in app.js, at “/login”, as I wrote above. Is this what your question is about?

Comment: I still don't get it. How are you going from the event listener to the controller? And why is the controller sending a redirect, if it's call from AJAX?

Comment: @Barmar Ok, so this is what happens (or what it should happen) after the user clicks on the submit button: The backend checks if the user is in the database and if the password is correct, it logs the user info in the terminal (just for checking that it went so far) and it sets the res.status to 200. Then, all the code with the “if (response.status == 200)” runs. Then, all the code in replaceWithUsername.js runs (or should run)

Comment: As I was writing this, I realized that none of the console.log following the if and else work, so the code does not arrive there.

Comment: What submit button? The HTML doesn't have a form or submit button. Do you mean `<div class="loginbutton"><a href="signin.html">Sign in</a></div>`?

Comment: No, there is a submit button in the sign in page (signin.html). It is the one that has the id "wantedSpace". I did not put it in the question as I did not think it would make a difference. It is defined as <input type="text" name="usernameOrEmail" placeholder="Username or Email" class="login_page_input" id="wantedSpace">

Comment: To answer your question we need to see how control and data flow between the pages.

Comment: I updated the question, but I am not sure what else I should upload for everyone to see how control and data flow between pages

Comment: I'm looking for the code with something like `fetch('/login').then(...)`

Comment: I don't have anything with "fetch", and the only part with "/login" is in the app.js, above. I tried to remove the if statement altogether, but the localStorage still doesn't recognize any of the new data I put there

Comment: So how are you calling the controller? Do you have `<form action="/login">`?

Comment: Yes, above the input I have <form action="http://localhost:3000/login" method="POST">. The input is a child of that form.

Comment: If you don't use `fetch()`, there's no `response`. It redirects to `/allPages/index.html` and it starts fresh.

Comment: You're trying to use JS code that processes an AJAX response in a page that's just loaded normally.

Comment: Ok, so where should I use fetch()? I suppose it's not like app.post( fetch('/login)...), right? Maybe I could update the question after your answer, so that we both have the code in front of us

Comment: With or without the AJAX, it should have worked when I deleted the if() statement and kept only what was inside of it, without any restriction

Comment: If you do that, you'll set `isLoggedIn` even if the controller doesn't find a matching user. It sets the variable as soon as the user types into the input field, without waiting for authentication.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But it didn't happen like this, the site acted like nothing changed, even after closing it and starting again

Comment: The `input` event happens after each character you type in the input field. So after typing the first character of the username, you're going to save that in local storage and redirect to `index.html`. You'll never submit the form because you won't get a chance to click in the submit button.

Comment: You should add a listener for the `submit` event, not `input`. But really, you should rethink the whole way you're doing this.  Use AJAX as it looks like you originally intended.